# Optimal static feedback gain matrix for stabilization

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Consider a system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = (A+KC)x(t) + K w(t)
$$
where $w(t)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is an unknown disturbance; $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ are known matrices with $(A,C)$ being a detectable pair; and $K\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a design matrix that must minimize $\mathcal{H}_2$-norm of transfer matrix
$$
T_K(s) = [sI - (A+KC)]^{-1} K.
$$
That is,
$$\boxed{\begin{array}{cl}
\displaystyle \min_{K\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}} & \mbox{trace}(W_K) \\
\mbox{subject to} & A+KC ~\mbox{is Hurwitz}
\end{array}}$$
where $\|T_K\|_{\mathcal{H}_2}=\sqrt{\mbox{trace}(W_K)}$ and
$$
W_K = \int_0^\infty \exp((A+KC) t) KK^T \exp((A+KC)^T t) dt
$$
is the controllability gramian of $(A+KC,K)$.

I discussed with some researchers who told me that this problem can be solvable using LMIs, however, they don't know how and they didn't give me any reference. I checked several books on robust control and I see that this problem is related to (1) disturbance attenuation problem and (2) optimal static feedback design under noise. However, the problem setups in (1) and (2) are different and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated. The solution regarding $\mathcal{H}_\infty$ is also welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: There is something weird with the notation here. In standard notation, for a dynamical system $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu, y = Cx$, the dynamics of the closed loop with state feedback would be $A + BK$ while the dynamics for an observer would be given by $A + KC$. The notation you have is not state-feedback dynamics with unorthodox variable naming (as $K$ is on the wrong side then).

Comment: Nevertheless, since it effectively is an H2 observer design, it should be answered on page 130 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08599.pdf

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to the Kalman Filter.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use LMI's? Namely, in this $\mathcal{H}_2$-norm case there is a simple analytical solution.

Comment: And yes, the solution is essentially an edge case of the Kalman filter.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to solve using LMI's. Can you show the analytical solution?

Comment: I always use this bible when I'm dealing with LMIs https://www.imng.uni-stuttgart.de/mst/files/LectureNotes.pdf Section 4.2.5 is on H2 design

Answer (score 1):

Because $A + K\,C$ is Hurwitz it [can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability_Gramian#Controllability_Gramian) that the Gramian can also be calculated by solving

$$
(A + K\,C)\,W + W\,(A + K\,C)^\top = -K\,K^\top. \tag{1}
$$

Furthermore, it can also be shown that the optimal solution has to satisfy

$$
K = -W\,C^\top. \tag{2}
$$

Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ yields the following algebraic Riccati equation

$$
A\,W + W\,A^\top - W\,C^\top C\,W = 0, \tag{3}
$$

which has a positive definite solution for $W$ if $A$ is not singular. This is also the algebraic Riccati equation associated with the stationary [continuous time Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Kalman%E2%80%93Bucy_filter) with the covariance of the process noise being zero.

---

It can be noted that the associated Hamiltonian matrix, which can be used to obtain the solution to $(3)$ such that $A + K\,C$ is Hurwitz, is given by

$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A^\top & -C^\top C \\
0 & -A
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which due to its upper block triangular structure implies that $H$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$ and $-A$. The resulting Hurwitz $A + K\,C$ has the same eigenvalues as the negative eigenvalues of $H$. Therefore, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ the matrix $A + K\,C$ has the eigenvalue $-|\lambda|$. Thus if $A$ is already Hurwitz means that $A + K\,C$ has the same eigenvalues and thus $K=0$.